# Using PCSC to read smartcard events in Winforms

Tags: smartcard

I'm trying to write a program that reads events from smartcard. I'm using https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp library.

I want to log the generated events to a textbox . I'm couldn't figure out how to do this. I'm unable to write those events to the form where I initiate the monitor.

I tried several workarounds like Invoke , BeginInvoke but the data is never writen to the form

Does someone can help me on this ?

Thanks

```
private  void DisplayEvent(string eventName, CardStatusEventArgs unknown)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(">> {0} Event for reader: {1}", eventName, unknown.ReaderName);
            Console.WriteLine("ATR: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(unknown.Atr ?? new byte[0]));
            Console.WriteLine("State: {0}\n", unknown.State);

}
```

This function receives the events generated by smartcard, but I can't send the state to the form